# Filter out elements in a list of lists

Tags: list, apache-spark, filter, tuples

I have the following RDD (List[List[String]]):

```
val x: List[List[String]] = List(List("0029", "029070", "99999", "19010101"), List("270", "1", "N", "0159"))
val data = sc.parallelize(x)
```

I want to remove from each list elements at index 0 and 3, for example:

```
val removeElements = List(0, 3)
data.map(_.zipWithIndex).collect.filter { a => !removeElements.contains(a._2) }.map { _._1 }
```

But this results in an error that I am unable to fix:

```
<console>:28: error: value _2 is not a member of List[(String, Int)]
          data.map(_.zipWithIndex).collect.filter { a => !toRemove.contains(a._2) }.map { _._1 }
```

In addition, it would be nice if I could map the results directly to a case class like:

```
case class MyData(a: String, b: String)
```

I found out that I could use MyData.tupled(data) as soon as I have filtered the data variable to have just 2 elements each.

Looking forward to any help on this issue!

Comment: Do you want to remove or retain those two values? Please share expected output.

Comment: I would like to remove values at the given indices. The expected output would be List(List("029070", "99999"), List("1", "N"))

Comment: what's wrong with `data.map(x=>(x(1),x(2)))` ?